# How do I disable the wireframes on particles

Tags: particles

I always get these bounding boxe wireframes around my hair particles on rugs which makes it difficult to see how my strands are looking before i render.

I've played with the Viewport display settings regarding wireframes and even when turned off, nothing changes with my issue. They only show up with certain rugs I get from the Blenderkit Addon.

How do I turn off these wireframes on particles on in my viewport?

[image: hair particles on rug have black wireframes]